# Proving the Non-existence of an Orthogonal Vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

If $X$ is vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with all components > 0 then is it true that a non-zero vector, $Y$, with all components ≥ 0, can not be orthogonal to $X$ ?

Considering the angles that $X$ makes with the coordinate axes seems to show there is no such $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for n = 2 and n = 3.

I am not sure how (or if) an angle-based proof can be extended to $\mathbb{R}^n$  for n ≥ 4 where intuition about angles fails.

Any suggestions or references related to how to prove the non-existence of $Y$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$  for n ≥ 4 would be appreciated.

**Response to Answer and Comment from Adayah  (26 July 2015)**

The response from Adayah shows what I thought were details I could leave out of the above question infact should have been included. Apologies for over-simplifying.

The problem I was considering was when the inner product $(X,Y)\rightarrow 0$
as the dimension $n\rightarrow \infty$ so Y is orthogonal to X in the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$ but not for finite n. The components of X are weights $\in \mathbb{R}(0,1)$, they sum to one, and each weight $\rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

Given the properties of X and Y, I would like to show there is no Y orthogonal  to X in the limit $n\rightarrow\infty$.

The solution suggested by Adayah does not work in this situation unless it can be shown that $X_iY_i$ stays non-zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: The 0 vector is orthogonal to every vector.

Comment: @ YoTengoUnLCD : That is the reason for the condition in the question that the vector Y is non-zero.

Comment: @Adayah : Thanks for the hint. I know orthogonality is equivalent to the inner product being zero but I do not know how to imply from that the non-existence of the vector Y in general..

Comment: Fix  an arbitrary vector $Y$ as in question. All terms $x_i \cdot y_i$ of the inner product are non-negative; they are $0$ if $y_i = 0$, but there is some $j$ such that $y_j > 0$...

Comment: @Adayah - Please refer to my response in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by taking the limit as $n\to\infty$?  What exactly are $X$ and $Y$?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey : What I mean by $(X,Y)\rightarrow 0$ as the dimension $n\rightarrow \infty$ is the usual definition of a limit. For all $\varepsilon > 0$ there is a $N(\varepsilon)$ such that n > $N(\varepsilon)$ implies $(X,Y)$ is in an $\varepsilon$ -neighbourhood of zero. The only property of X and Y not already specified is that the components of Y that are non-zero have a positive lower bound independent of n.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what you're trying to ask.  Would $X_n=(1/n,1/n,\dots,1/n)\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y_n=(1,0,0,\dots,0)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a counterexample?

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: Your example is a counter example and it could be generalized as follows: If X has the properties I specified and Y is a linear combination of basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the coefficients and their number independent of n, then X and Y are orthogonal in the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$.
This form of Y is a Sufficient Condition for X and Y to be orthogonal in the limit $n\rightarrow \infty$. What I am looking for are Necessary Conditions on the form of Y.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $X = (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$ is orthogonal to $Y = (y_1, \ldots, y_n)$ iff $x_1 y_1 + \ldots + x_n y_n = 0.$